# Bang operator not working for distributed node

Tags: erlang

I am trying to run a command to a distributed Erlang node (on localhost) and I get the following error:

```
(adi@127.0.0.1)7> A=spawn('dan@127.0.0.1',sv,start,[]).
<12104.115.0>
(adi@127.0.0.1)13> nodes().
['dan@127.0.0.1']
(adi@127.0.0.1)17> {'adi@127.0.0.1',A} ! {self(),aa}. 
** exception error: bad argument
     in operator  !/2
        called as {'adi@127.0.0.1',<12104.115.0>} ! {<0.125.0>,aa}
```

I tried using the `node` name `dan@127.0.0.1`   without the `` to no avail.
Why does the bang pattern not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct error, you cannot send message to the tuple, you can send message only to some process:

```erlang
1> self() ! {self(), hello}.
{<0.79.0>,hello}
2> flush().
Shell got {<0.79.0>,hello}
ok
3> {} ! {self(), hello}.    
** exception error: bad argument
     in operator  !/2
        called as {} ! {<0.79.0>,hello}
```

So, for your case you need send message like:

```erlang
1> A = spawn('dan@127.0.0.1', sv, start, []).
2> A ! {self(), aa}.
```

More useful information [Concurrent Programming](https://erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html).

Comment: I was thinking that in order to use the `bang` operator for another node you need to provide `{nodename,pid}`   , but in my case the `spawn/4` already provides all information in order to send messages to other nodes.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a process id for a process on another node, you don't need to specify the node name when sending messages to id, since the pid already contains the node name. So try this:

```
A=spawn('dan@127.0.0.1',sv,start,[]).
A ! {self(),aa}.
```